# Implementing a favorite button in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview

I'm trying to implement a favorite button in an app and this is my attempt. This is what I currently have:

```
let favoriteButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var emptyHeartImg = UIImage(named: "emptyheart")
    var fullHeartImg = UIImage(named: "fullheart")
    emptyHeartImg = emptyHeartImg?.maskWithColor(color: UIColor(r: 128, g: 171, b: 103))
    fullHeartImg = fullHeartImg?.maskWithColor(color: UIColor(r: 128, g: 171, b: 103))
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: emptyHeartImg, highlightedImage: fullHeartImg)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    button.setImage(imageView.image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleFavorite), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc private func handleFavorite() {
    if (favoriteButton.imageView?.isHighlighted)! == false {
        favoriteButton.imageView?.isHighlighted = true
    } else {
        favoriteButton.imageView?.isHighlighted = false
    }
}
```

Currently this doesn't change the image as desired. Any tips or alternative methods to implementing a favorite button?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `UIButton.isSelected` instead of the highlight state of the imageView. I am not sure about `UIImageView`, but `isHighlighted` for buttons is only when they are actively being touched, not a persistent state. See the lines marked **:

```
let favoriteButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var emptyHeartImg = UIImage(named: "emptyheart")
    var fullHeartImg = UIImage(named: "fullheart")
    emptyHeartImg = emptyHeartImg?.maskWithColor(color: UIColor(r: 128, g: 171, b: 103))
    fullHeartImg = fullHeartImg?.maskWithColor(color: UIColor(r: 128, g: 171, b: 103))
    **button.setImage(emptyHeartImg, for: .normal)
    **button.setImage(fullHeartImg, for: .selected)
    **button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleFavorite), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

And then in your handler:

```
favoriteButton.isSelected = !favoriteButton.isSelected
```